# How to check edittext

Tags: android

I want to add a verification to my edit text:

- check if the name is not a number
- check if the tel is a number
- check if the password and password2 are equals

How can I do this?

```
if (name.isEmpty() || name.length() < 3 ||  ............) {
     et_name.setError("enter a valid name");
     valid = false;
} else {
     et_nom.setError(null);
}
if (tel.isEmpty() || ..........) {
     et_tel.setError("enter a valid tel");
     valid = false;
} else {
     et_tel.setError(null);
}
if (password.isEmpty() || password2.isEmpty() || ..........) {
     et_password.setError("enter a valid password");
     valid = false;
} else {
     et_password.setError(null);
}
```

Comment: Why not just set the `inputType="number"` of the `editText` in the xml?

Answer (score 2):

Okey...

**first :**

for name you don't want allow user to enter numbers so what you can do is add two attributes to your name `EditText`.

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "
android:inputType="text"
```

This will allow user to enter only alphabets and blank space. so no need for verification on that programmatically.

**Second :**

Same for the telephone number. you have to add `android:inputType="number"` to your telephone `EditText`. So user will able to input numbers only.

**Third**

for validating if your `EditText` is empty or not you can do following.

```
if (name.getText().toString().equals("")) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Please enter your name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**Fourth**

For checking password equality you can do following.

```
if (!password1.getText().toString().equals(password2.getText().toString())) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Please enter your name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Now Hopefully you understand this whole process. for your case refer following code.

```
if (name.getText().toString().equals("") || name.length() < 3 ||) {
        et_name.setError("enter a valid name");
        valid = false;
} 
if (tel.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        et_tel.setError("enter a valid tel");
        valid = false;
} 
if (password.getText().toString().equals("") || password2.getText().toString().equals("") || !password.getText().toString().equals(password2.getText().toString())) {
        et_password.setError("enter a valid password");
        valid = false;
}
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

1. Why not just set the `inputType="number"` of the `EditText` in the xml? If you still prefer checking it dynamically, check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12569609/4625829).
2. TextUtils.equals() - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#equals(java.lang.CharSequence, java.lang.CharSequence)

Cheers! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try using android.text.Utils.TextUtils class (part of android SDK)

See [inputType](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html)

**1. Check if name is number**

```java
if(TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(str)) {
  //number
}
```

**2. Check if name is not a number**

```java
if(!TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(str)) {
  //number
}
```

**3. Check if two password1 and password2 are equal**

```java
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(password1) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(password2) && !password1.equals(password2)) {
  //number
}
```